# network adapter for bridge being deleted vmware

Tags: networking, vmware-player

When I tried to use Ubuntu with bridge it says that I don't have a connection to the internet.  The message I receive says "network connection activation failed."

When I saw the Virtual Network Editor in VMware and everything was right, but then I went to network adapters and the adapter for bridge (vm0) was not there.  It was my NAT and Host only adapter only.

I reset the values of the Network Editor to their defaults and it showed the Bridge adapter, but some seconds after it disappeared.  That's why I think I don't have connection in my Ubuntu VM.  How can I solve that and why is that happening?

As I show in the picture VMnet0 is not in the picture because it is always automatically deleted after I reset the default configuration.

[image: VMnet0 is not shown because it is always automatically deleted after I reset the default configuration.]

I tried to create a host only connection so that way a new adapter is created.  Then I configured it to be bridge, but when I select that adapter as bridge in Vmware, the adapter gets deleted again.

[image: When I set the new adapter as bridge in VMware, the adapter gets deleted again.]

Comment: Try the following:  Remove VMNet2, close out your Guest machines (shut them down), go to Programs, VMware, VMware Network Editor, and then click on the Admin Button in the Editor and then reset the VMware Network. Restart your computer and try setting up your Guest machine in Bridged Mode again.

Comment: @John I already did that, I always reset the Vmware Network and it creates the adapter for bridge but it's inmediatelly deleted and I don't know why, I desactivated Firewall and Antivirus but even so it doesn't work

Comment: There is a new version of VMware out (15.5.5). Try both the new VMware version and also make a new Linux machine to see if the problem is the guest machine or the host OS and/or VMware.